# How is the copy constructor being invoked from derived class copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a below program, and I wonder how the copy constructor of base class is invoked.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
    int a;
    public:
    Base(int xinput):a(xinput)
    {
        cout<<"Base Ctor:" << a<<endl;

        counter++;
    }
    Base(const Base &obj)
    {

        a=obj.a;
        cout<<"base copy ctr:"<<a<<endl;
        counter++;
    }
    void printcounter()
    {
        cout<<"Base counter:"<<counter<<endl;
    }
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        cout<<"Base Dtor:"<<a<<endl;
        counter--;
    }
    protected:
    static int counter;
};

class Derived:public Base
{
    int b;
    public:
    Derived(int xinput,int yinput):Base(xinput),b(yinput)
    {
        cout<<"Derived Ctor:" << b<<endl;

        counter++;
    }
    void printcounter()
    {
        cout<<"Derived counter:"<<counter<<endl;
    }
     ~Derived()
    {
        cout<<"Derived Dtor:" <<b<<endl;
        counter--;
    }
};
int Base::counter = 0;
Derived d(22,22);
int main()
{
    {
        Derived D(d);          
        Base *bptr = new Derived(d);
        bptr->printcounter();
        delete bptr;
        d.printcounter();

    }
    d.printcounter();

    return 0;
}
```

output is as below.

```
Base Ctor:22
Derived Ctor:22
base copy ctr:22 //Why is base copy Ctor invoked
base copy ctr:22
Base counter:4
Derived Dtor:22
Base Dtor:22
Derived counter:2
Derived Dtor:22
Base Dtor:22
Derived counter:0
Derived Dtor:22
Base Dtor:22
```

Since I have not defined copy constructor in derived class implicit copy constructor is invoked. But how is copy constructor of Base class invoked from there. Can someone tell internal mechanism.

Comment: `Derived D(d);`  -- What does this line do?

Comment: This calls copy constructor of Derived class. But how is copy constructor of base class invoked from that. As copy constructor is not chained.

Comment: If the class does not define an explicit copy constructor, it gets a default one (with some exceptions that are immaterial here). Whether the class is the most-derived class, or a superclass of another class, does not matter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know if explicit copy constructor is not provided, implicit copy constructor is called. I want to know the internal mechanism of how copy constructor of base class being invoked.

Comment: The "internal mechanism" is something that the C++ compiler needs to worry about, and not you. But, this "internal mechanism" is that it gets automatically invoked by the child class's copy constructor, which itself can be both an implicit or an explicit process. If the child class has a default copy constructor, it calls the default parent class's copy constructor. If the child class has an explicit copy constructor, and it doesn't explicitly construct the parent class, the parent class's default constructor gets called. If the parent class has no default constructor, it is ill-formed.

Comment: @arjunjawalkar -- *But how is copy constructor of base class invoked from that.* -- How can you have a `D` object without having a `B` parent constructed in some way?  Maybe you misunderstand object-oriented programming fundamentals.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have cleared my doubt myself. I wanted to know if implicit copy constructor of derived class has a initializer list with Base class copy constructor on it. And yet it has. I have added the answer with example. I was hoping the C++ gurus here would explain it to me. Sad that the question was got down voted but proper answer was not given.

Comment: My point is simple -- a `Derived` object exists.  There is no way a `Derived` object can exist without a `Base` object existing.  How did the `Base` get created?  Something created it, and that something is the copy constructor.  Basically, every object that exists has to be created somehow, including that object's class hierarchy, so that's why it seemed strange to me that you didn't understand this concept.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I have not defined copy constructor in derived class implicit copy constructor is invoked.

Correct.

> But how is copy constructor of Base class invoked from there.

Its unclear what you mean by "how". An implicit copy constructor copies all sub-objects. This includes base sub-objects.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer that I am looking for.

Since the derived class does not have explicit copy constructor, compiler defines its own copy constructor and this copy constructor has an initialize list where copy constructor is invoked.

```
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    A(int x){cout<<"A::Default ctr"<<endl;}
    A(const A& obj){cout<<"A::copy Ctr"<<endl;}
};

class B:public A
{
    public:
    B(int x):A(x){cout<<"B::Default ctr"<<endl;}
    B(const B& obj):A(obj)
    {cout<<"B::copy Ctr"<<endl;}
};
int main()
{
        B bobj(10);
        B b1obj(bobj);
}
```

In the above code if you remove A(obj) present in initialize list of B class copy constructor you get compilation error. So it is thus clear that when you have any variable that needs to be passed on the base class constructor as part of its initialization the implicit copy constructor of derived class also provides an initializer list where base class copy constructor is called.